# Split words in a nested list into letters

Tags: python

I was wondering how I can split words in a nested list into their individual letters such that

```
[['ANTT'], ['XSOB']]
```

becomes

```
[['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]
```

Comment: @thg435: agreed. Strings are iterable anyway, so you can already do `for letter in sublist[0]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[list(l[0]) for l in mylist]
```

Your input list simply contains nested lists with 1 element each, so we need to use `l[0]` on each element. `list()` on a string creates a list of the individual characters:

```
>>> mylist = [['ANTT'], ['XSOB']]
>>> [list(l[0]) for l in mylist]
[['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]
```

If you ever fix your code to produce a straight up list of strings (so without the single-element nested lists), you only need to remove the `[0]`:

```
>>> mylist = ['ANTT', 'XSOB']
>>> [list(l) for l in mylist]
[['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could you a functional approach (still I would prefer list comprehensions as in Martijn Pieters' answer):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> delisted = map(itemgetter(0),[['ANTT'],['XSOB']])  # -> ['ANTT', 'XSOB']
>>> splited = map(list,delisted)  # -> [['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]
```

Or, as a oneliner:

```
>>> map(list,map(itemgetter(0),[['ANTT'],['XSOB']]))
[['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]
```

Comment: A nice use case for functional.compose: `map(compose(list, itemgetter(0)), xs)`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> map(lambda s: map(list, s)[0], [['ANTT'],['XSOB']])
[['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers given so far include a - somewhat suspicious - `0` literal. At first glance this seem to be a somewhat artificial additive, since the original task doesn't include any integer literal.

But the input has - of course - some **special properties** besides being just a list. It's a list of lists with exactly *one* string literal in it. In other words, a package of individually boxed objects (strings). If we rephrase the original question and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154766/2932052), we can make the relation between `[x]` and `[0]` more obvious:

```
package = [['ANTT'], ['XSOB']]
result = [list(box[0]) for box in package]   # 0 indicates first (and only) element in the box
```